# Why the spaces are not being printed in this for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, quoting

I have this code:

```
for i in 'some     text' "some     other     text"
do
    echo $i
done
```

The output is:

```
some text
some other text
```

Why the spaces are not being printed?

Comment: Please Read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/265604)

Comment: I don't think the down votes are all that appropriate, it is a well formatted and to the point question from a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Because it expands to

```
echo some text
```

which will result in the output you gave. That is why we should quote our variables in most cases. Try to replace `echo $i` with `echo "$i"` and see the difference.

Comment: I had thought that the command executed is still `echo some(many spaces here)text` but the spaces are trimmed when that command is executed. Did I miss something, or the concept that has been in my mind for long wrong?

Comment: If this is the case, thank you very much for correcting my long-held belief. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quote your expansions `echo "$i"`:

```
$ for i in 'some     text' "some     other     text"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Prints

```
some     text
some     other     text
```

Please [read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/265604).